# Как получить элемент массива имея все ключи до него

Tags: javascript

У меня есть массив

```
['one','two','three']
```

И объект

```
{
    'one':{
        'two':{
            'three': 'data'
        }
    }
}
```

как мне получить 'data'?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Один из способов - использовать функцию reduce.

```js
const props = ['one', 'two', 'three']

const data = {
  'one': {
    'two': {
      'three': 'data'
    }
  }
}

const val = props.reduce((elem, prop) => {
  return elem[prop];
}, data);

console.log(val);
```

Второй способ, с помощью обычного цикла.

```js
const props = ['one', 'two', 'three']

const data = {
  'one': {
    'two': {
      'three': 'data'
    }
  }
}
let val = data;
for (let i = 0; i < props.length; i++) {
  val = val[props[i]];
}

console.log(val);
```

Путь маньяка. НЕ ДЕЛАЙТЕ ТАК!

```js
const props = ['one', 'two', 'three']

const data = {
  'one': {
    'two': {
      'three': 'data'
    }
  }
}
const func = new Function('data', 'return data.' + props.join('.'));

const val = func(data);

console.log(val);
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var test_data = {
  'one': {
    'two': {
      'three': 'data'
    }
  }
};
var test_keys = ['one', 'two', 'three'];

function getSubitem(data, keys) {
  var current = data;
  for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
    current = current[keys[i]];
    if (!current)
      return null;
  }
  return current;
}

console.log(getSubitem(test_data, test_keys));
```

Answer (score 1):

- Можно давать путь через точки `'document.body.xyz'` или через массив
  `['document', 'body', 'xyz']`.
- Можно указать значение по умолчанию
- Для пути в виде строки можно задать произвольный разделитель(последний аргумент)

```js
function resolvePath (path, obj , orDefault = null, separator = '.') {
    const properties = Array.isArray(path) ? path : path.split(separator)
    return properties.reduce((prev, curr) => prev && prev[curr], obj) || orDefault
}

// Примеры использования
console.log(
resolvePath('document.body', window), // <body>
resolvePath('document.body.xyz', window), // null
resolvePath(['document', 'body', 'xyz'], window, 'defaultValue') // defaultValue
)
```